# Is there any function that returns the out edges of a node?

Tags: python, networkx

I am using python with networkx package. I need to find the nodes connected to out edges of a given node.
I know there is a function networkx.DiGraph.out_edges but it returns out edges for the entire graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a networkx expert, but have you tried [networkx.DiGraph.out_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_edges.html), specifying the source node?

> ```
> DiGraph.out_edges(nbunch=None, data=False)
> ```
>
> Return a list of edges.
>
> Edges are returned as tuples with optional data in the order (node,
>   neighbor, data).

If you just want the out edges for a single node, pass that node in inside the nbunch:

```
graph.out_edges([my_node])
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to use the successors() method:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G=nx.DiGraph([(0,1),(1,2)])

In [3]: G.edges()
Out[3]: [(0, 1), (1, 2)]

In [4]: G.successors(1)
Out[4]: [2]
```